# Intellisense not working properly for .aspx files in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

Recently, my intellisense stopped working for asp and user controls alike.

I start typing `<asp:` which should bring up a dropdown menu with suggestions like `<asp:Textbox` and `<asp:Label`, but all I am getting is `<asp:Content` instead of a full list of available controls.

[image: Picture of Expected Behavior]

[image: Picture of Current Behavior]

This is a problem with all of the visual studio projects/solutions that I have and It is unique to `.aspx` files. Intellisense is working for all other files types.

I've also noticed that the `*.designer.vb` files are not reloading/regenerating when I make changes to the corresponding `.aspx` file. Both issue seem to have started at the same time.

Update: I think it's worth mentioning that intellisense is also not functioning for javascript inside .aspx files as well (previously did). I'm not getting any html5 elements in the dropdown either. The properties window also is empty and there are no options to select from the drop down.

### Things I have tried

- Reinstalling Visual Studio 2019 Professional
- Repairing Visual Studio 2019 Professional
- Installing Visual Studio 2019 Community
- Disabling all third party extensions
- Re-cloning the project from the repository
- Deleting `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.x_xxxxxxxx`
- Deleting `[project].vbproj.*`
- Deleting `.vs` folder
- Matt's suggestion below: Making sure Intellicode is set up properly

---

I'm really scratching my head on this and I'm at the point where I'm considering reinstalling windows to start fresh.

I kinda think I might be missing some configuration files or something like that at the program level that aren't auto-generating.

Comment: check if any firewall blocking the visual studio -  in the last update I have so many issues that actually i was unable to code, so after 7 days - today I totally uninstall it, and reinstall the previous version that I found here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Aristos - I will try installing an earlier version.

Comment: And you do not need to clear the AppData - I have left it, and its take all my previous settings and works now just fine - 7 days now I am struggling with that... loose only extensions and tools  - I remove the 16.10.0 and put back the 16.9.6 - but remove all instance of 2019 all - and dont forget the firewall - if you block it its unable to communicate with intellisense (even local)

Comment: And you testing this on a blank new project each time?  Badly munched page of bad markup or incorrect markup will often be the issue . So does this problem exist for all projects - or just one really messed up and damaged project? On the other hand, leaving out this MASSIVE HUGE detail would be sheer folly - so I have to think that you testing on a brand new blank project - if that works, THEN and ONLY then do you open the project that has problems.

Comment: Yes, Albert, I've tested this on new projects and multiple other projects that I am working on. My coworkers who are working on the same projects are not experiencing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to Options -> Intellicode -> General and making sure everything is set up the way you need it? You can reach that dialog by typing in "Intellicode" in the Search bar.

Comment: All of the options were set to `Default`, so I set them all to `Enabled`. That seems to make intellisense work for the first few seconds a file is open, but the problem persists once the file has been open for longer than that.

Comment: Also make sure you have the latest version of Visual Studio 2019. It's currently version 16.10.0. And also make sure your NuGet packages are all up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that is the version that I am running